# How to setup error reporting in Stackdriver from kubernetes pods?

Tags: google-compute-engine, kubernetes, gcloud, fluentd, stackdriver

I'm a bit confused at how to setup error reporting in kubernetes, so errors are visible in Google Cloud Console / Stackdriver "Error Reporting"?

According to documentation
https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/setting-up-on-compute-engine
we need to enable fluentd' "forward input plugin" and then send exception data from our apps.  I think this approach would have worked if we had setup fluentd ourselves, but it's already pre-installed on every node in a pod that just runs  gcr.io/google_containers/fluentd-gcp docker image.

How do we enable forward input on those pods and make sure that http port available to every pod on the nodes? We also need to make sure this config is used by default when we add more nodes to our cluster.

Any help would be appreciated, may be I'm looking at all this from a wrong point?

Comment: Do you use GKE or GCE?

Comment: I am the product manager for Stackdriver Error Reporting. Currently, the feature is in beta and we do not officially support Kubernetes yet. We will try to provide our best answer here once we have a solution to share.

Comment: Thanks for response. We use GKE - we want to send error reporting from our java pods to Stackdriver Error Reporting. @Steren, thank you, looking forward to that.

Comment: I was able to get it to work as follows:
1. Create a docker image modeled after fluentd-gcp-image/Dockerfile, replacing the google-fluentd.conf contents with just the one section for the forward input plugin.
2. Create a replication controller and service for this dedicated fluentd forwarder so that your application can reach it over TCP.
3. Follow the example from our docs, replacing localhost and 24224 with the environment variable values from the service created in 2.
Sorry for being so terse! I need to clean up my example and post it, hopefully my outline above is already useful to you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The basic idea is to start a separate pod that receives structured logs over TCP and forwards it to Cloud Logging, similar to a locally-running fluentd agent. See below for the steps I used.

(Unfortunately, the logging support that is built into Docker and Kubernetes cannot be used - it just forwards individual lines of text from stdout/stderr as separate log entries which prevents Error Reporting from seeing complete stack traces.)

Create a docker image for a fluentd forwarder using a `Dockerfile` as follows:

```
FROM gcr.io/google_containers/fluentd-gcp:1.18

COPY fluentd-forwarder.conf /etc/google-fluentd/google-fluentd.conf
```

Where `fluentd-forwarder.conf` contains the following:

```
<source>
  type forward
  port 24224
</source>

<match **>
  type google_cloud
  buffer_chunk_limit 2M
  buffer_queue_limit 24
  flush_interval 5s
  max_retry_wait 30
  disable_retry_limit
</match>
```

Then build and push the image:

```
$ docker build -t gcr.io/###your project id###/fluentd-forwarder:v1 .
$ gcloud docker push gcr.io/###your project id###/fluentd-forwarder:v1
```

You need a replication controller (`fluentd-forwarder-controller.yaml`):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: fluentd-forwarder
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      name: fluentd-forwarder
      labels:
        app: fluentd-forwarder
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: fluentd-forwarder
        image: gcr.io/###your project id###/fluentd-forwarder:v1
        env:
        - name: FLUENTD_ARGS
          value: -qq
        ports:
        - containerPort: 24224
```

You also need a service (`fluentd-forwarder-service.yaml`):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: fluentd-forwarder
spec:
  selector:
    app: fluentd-forwarder
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 24224
```

Then create the replication controller and service:

```
$ kubectl create -f fluentd-forwarder-controller.yaml
$ kubectl create -f fluentd-forwarder-service.yaml
```

Finally, in your application, instead of using 'localhost' and 24224 to connect to the fluentd agent as described on https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/setting-up-on-compute-engine, use the values of evironment variables `FLUENTD_FORWARDER_SERVICE_HOST` and `FLUENTD_FORWARDER_SERVICE_PORT`.

Comment: thank you for your input Boris! that's pretty much what we ended up with :)

Comment: You're welcome. Do your errors show up as expected? Please file feedback if you have any - use the "!" icon on the top right of the console when looking at an Error Reporting page and the team will receive that directly. Thanks!

Comment: Setting up the fluentd client in the application can be modeled after this: https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/setup/ec2

Answer (score 1):

To add to Boris' answer: As long as errors are logged in the right format (see https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/troubleshooting) and Cloud Logging is enabled (you can see the errors in https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer) then errors will make it to Error Reporting without any further setup.

Answer (score 0):

Boris' answer was great but was a lot more complicated then it really needed to be (no need to build a docker image).  If you have kubectl configured on your local box (or you can use the Google Cloud Shell), copy and paste the following and it will install the forwarder in your cluster (I updated the version of fluent-gcp from the above answer).  My solution uses a ConfigMap to store the file so it can be changed easily without rebuilding.

```
cat << EOF | kubectl create -f -
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: fluentd-forwarder
data:
  google-fluentd.conf: |+
    <source>
      type forward
      port 24224
    </source>

    <match **>
      type google_cloud
      buffer_chunk_limit 2M
      buffer_queue_limit 24
      flush_interval 5s
      max_retry_wait 30
      disable_retry_limit
    </match>

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: fluentd-forwarder
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      name: fluentd-forwarder
      labels:
        app: fluentd-forwarder
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: fluentd-forwarder
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/fluentd-gcp:2.0.18
        env:
        - name: FLUENTD_ARGS
          value: -qq
        ports:
        - containerPort: 24224
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config-vol
          mountPath: /etc/google-fluentd
      volumes:
        - name: config-vol
          configMap:
            name: fluentd-forwarder
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: fluentd-forwarder
spec:
  selector:
    app: fluentd-forwarder
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 24224
EOF
```