# Google container engine logging to Stackdriver Error Reporting

Tags: google-app-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, fluentd, stackdriver, google-cloud-error-reporting

I'm currently trying to log errors to Stackdriver Error Reporting from Google Container Engine. I'm using the built-in fluentd-based Stackdriver Logging agent from GKE which works great. However, when I log an error according to the specification(https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/formatting-error-messages), I do not see it appear in Stackdriver Error Reporting

The payload I see in Stackdriver Logging is

```
{
 insertId: "xatjb4fltv246"   
 jsonPayload: {
  stream: "event"    
  message: "path was incorrect"    
  environment: "production"    
  event_type: "RAILS_ERROR"    
  context: {
   path: "/2",
    reportLocation: {
      functionName: "foo"      
      filePath: "/something.js"      
      lineNumber: 3      
    }     
   request_id: "3149e5c4-3192-4a9c-a123-b4dedf5a9e07"     
  }
  timestamp: 1492205840    
  serviceContext: {
   service: "nambrotdotcom"     
  }
 }
 resource: {…}   
 timestamp: "2017-04-14T21:37:20Z"   
 severity: "INFO"   
 labels: {…}   
 logName: "projects/nambrotdotcom/logs/web"   
}
```

If I understand correctly, this should be fine?

EDIT:

I logged a manual error according to the trouble shooting page and it worked fine. The only difference I see between the error I manually logged and the payload I logged from GKE is that the logname and labels are different, but that shouldn't be a factor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error Reporting is looking for severity `ERROR` or higher, but will also consider `DEFAULT` in most cases. The problem is the
     `severity: "INFO"`
value in the log entry.

Comment: That was it! Thanks!