# How to log custom metrics in Google Container Engine to Stackdriver?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, monitoring, google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver

I'm currently exploring more and more of Google Cloud Platform and try to evaluate how I can change my default stack. I like the idea of using all the built-in tooling instead of having to go to various Saas products. One of the more open questions has been how to make use of Stackdriver Monitoring. I understand that the built-in monitoring uses Heapster with the Google Cloud Sink. However, how do I expose my own custom metrics to Stackdriver for use? I don't mean the logs-based metrics, but the real thing?

I know I could always install the agent myself onto the cluster, but it appears to me that as part of Google Container Engine, it is already running, so how could I push metrics to it?

Answer (score 1):

The fluentd pod pre-installed in GKE is in kube-system namespace and managed by k8s, so you shouldn't mess with it. Currently it seems only proxying stdout/stderr to Stackdriver. But according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41875676/5039117), k8s team is working on providing accessible node-wide fluentd port out of the box.

[This document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/) has details about setting up custom logging.

Comment: As I asked in my other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43451973/google-container-engine-logging-to-stackdriver-error-reporting, Stackdriver Error Reporting is indeed already doable with the built-in integration of fluent-d that listens to stdout.

However, what's unclear to me is whether Stackdriver Monitoring can do the same. Unless I'm misunderstanding your comment about fluentd being accessible

Comment: I meant currently making changes to pre-installed pods are not supported so it is not practical to add custom metrics. The pre-installed fluentd is configured to stream stdout/stderr to stackdriver error report so when you output to stdout/stderr, it will go to stackdriver. But monitor metrics is different things.

Comment: Yeah I was afraid that was the case. I guess my only hope for out of the box integration is for Kubernetes to expose monitoring somehow and have stackdriver automatically consume that for application metrics

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, the best strategy for now seems to be using https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/k8s-stackdriver/tree/master/prometheus-to-sd

Answer (score -2):

I think GCP already give us related docs, see [Using Custom Metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/)

Comment: Crazykev, could you elaborate? I'm not sure how I can log custom metrics without installing the agent myself. Ideally, I would like to reuse the mechanism that GKE provides, but as far as I can tell, that is not possible?