# Google Stackdriver Logging doesn't work in Google Cloud Shell nor GKE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-shell, google-kubernetes-engine

I've built a docker image for GKE, and want to use Google Stackdriver Logging.

For the moment I'm just trying to log `Service started` when a service starts.

While running the container on my host works well (In `Google Cloud Console` > `Logs Viewer` > `Global`, I can see `Service started` when expected), running the container the exact same way on Google Cloud Shell doesn't log anything. Deploying to GKE does the exact same behavior, no errors but I can't find the supposedly created logs.

Here are the scopes for my cluster:
`cloud-platform,compute-rw,datastore,default,storage-full,logging-write,service-control,service-management`.

Note that the logging client gets successfully created:

```
client, err := logging.NewClient(ctx, projectID)

if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Failed to create the logging client: %v", err)
} else {
    fmt.Println("Logging client created")
}

app.Logger = client.Logger(logName)

text := "Started service !"

app.Logger.Log(logging.Entry{
    Payload: text,
})
```

I get "Logging client created" every time in my cluster logs, or when running the container manually inside the Google Cloud Shell.
But I get "Started service !" only when running the container on my own machine.

Answer (score 1):

I ran the `gcloud logging` command:

```
gcloud logging read "logName=projects/${PROJECT_ID}/logs/${LOG_NAME}"
```

and I found out the `type: gce_instance` instead of the expected `type: global`.

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/45085569/7046455 I found my logs under `GCE VM Instance`.

It is quite surprising NOT to be able to simply gets all the logs by log name on the Google Cloud Console, while it is possible on the CLI...

EDIT: these are actually the logs from the Google Cloud Shell, NOT from my containers ! I still haven't found out why my logs are not created in my cluster ...